# forcing a traffic redirect?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, iptables

I am trying to get my machines to be force through a MiTM and the MiTM to redirect them to a server of my choice (which happens to be the MiTM on port 17002)

I am running ip tables:

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2:17002

I am then using ettercap to ARP the targets and force the traffic through the hacking machine... but all I can do is either DoS the machine OR just allow it to pass through... I cannot get it to redirect.. I can access the server by typing it in the browsers url bar so I know the server works and can be accessed remotely.

I just want any traffic to be stopped and changed to my server... any help?